# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 \dots \int_0^1 f(\sqrt[n]{x_1\dots x_n})dx_1\dots dx_n = f(\frac{1}{e}).$ $f$ is continuous on $[0;1].$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

$f$ is continuous on $[0;1].$ Prove $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{n} f(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n})\mathrm \, dx_1\cdots \mathrm dx_n = f(\frac{1}{e}).$$

At first, I thought that we should get inside the function with the limit, but it's probably restricted due to $dx_1\dots dx_n$. I feel like I'm missing an important Theorem here. And yet it seems like the problem should be easy. Can somebody smart help me out here (at least with a hint) ?

Perhaps, it's an induction method problem.

Comment: You can proceed as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757330/how-prove-this-integral-limit-f-frac12/759320#759320). If $f$ were a polynomial try to show that the limit is $f(1/e)$ and then pass to any continuous function $f$ using Weierstrass approximation.

Comment: omg, that's a super helpful hint. Thank you!

Comment: Cool! Let me know when you get it.

Comment: The title is not coherent. Please rewrite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A short solution could be. Consider the random variables $u_1,...,u_n$  which they are i.i.d with density function $\rho(u)=e^{-u}$ (exponential distribution with $\lambda =1 $). So the expected value $E[u] = \int^{\infty}_{0}u\cdot e^{-u}du = 1$. By law of large numbers $\frac{S_n}{n}\to E[u]=1$. Where $S_n := u_1+..+u_n$. Observe that 
$$\int_{0}^1\dots\int_{0}^1f(\sqrt[n]{x_1...x_n})dx_1\dots dx_n = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dots\int_{0}^{\infty}f(e^{-\frac{S_n}{n}}) e^{-u_1}du_1...e^{-u_n}du_n =E[f(e^{-\frac{S_n}{n}})]$$
Finally by continuity and dominated convergence
$$E[f(e^{-\frac{S_n}{n}})] \xrightarrow{n} E[f(e^{-1})]=f(e^{-1}).$$

Comment: very clever. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Here's an elementary proof. Suppose $f(x) = x^k$ then we see that
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\cdots \int^1_0 dx_1\cdots dx_n\ f(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n})=&\ \int^1_0\cdots \int^1_0 dx_1\cdots dx_n\ \left(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n} \right)^k\\
=&\ \left(\int^1_0 dx\ x^{\frac{k}{n}} \right)^n = \left(1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^{-n}.
\end{align}
In particular, it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^1_0\cdots \int^1_0 dx_1\cdots dx_n\ f(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^{-n} = \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^k.
\end{align}
If $f$ is a polynomial, then it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^1_0\cdots \int^1_0 dx_1\cdots dx_n\ f(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}) = f\left( \frac{1}{e}\right).
\end{align}

Next, if $f$ is continuous, then, by Wierestrass approximation theorem, there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_m$ such that $p_m \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$. Finally, it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^1_0\cdots \int^1_0 dx_1\cdots dx_n\ f(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}) =&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^1_0\cdots \int^1_0 dx_1\cdots dx_n\ \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}p_m(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n})\\
=&\  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\int^1_0\cdots \int^1_0 dx_1\cdots dx_n\ p_m(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n})\\
=&\ \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^1_0\cdots \int^1_0 dx_1\cdots dx_n\ p_m(\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n})\\
=&\ \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} p_m\left(\frac{1}{e} \right) = f\left(\frac{1}{e} \right).
\end{align}

Comment: I can't understand second and third = signs in your proof. You raise to power n as if f is out of integral and the next step you are taking an integral with f within the integral...

Comment: @EstMayhem, The second step is a special instance of the following observation: $$\int\limits_{[a_1,b_1]\times\dots\times[a_n,b_n]} g_1(x_1)\dots g_n(x_n) \, \mathrm{d}x_1\dots\mathrm{d}x_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\int_{a_k}^{b_k} g_k(x_k) \, \mathrm{d}x_k. $$ Of course, this is a simple application of the Fubini's Theorem. Then the third step follows from $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{1+\alpha}, \qquad \alpha > -1 $$